# What can be the cause of an empty NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, exception, classloader

I receive a NoClassDefFoundError with a message value of null. That I does not know which class has the initialize problem. The top level trace is the constructor of a class and not the static part of a class. What can be the cause of such exception?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at com.company.xyz.FooBar.<init>(FooBar:76) 
    ....
```

Code on the line 76 of FooBar:

```
drv = data.get( i ).getDrivers();
drvnameToAdd = Msg.getMsg( "msgkey" ); <-- line 76
allNotImported.add( drvnameToAdd );
```

some code from class Msg:

```
private static final ResourceBundle LANGUAGE_RESOURCES;
static {
    LANGUAGE_RESOURCES = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "com.company.xyz.i18n.LanguageResources" );
}

public static String getMsg( String msgID ) {
    String msg;
    try {
        msg = LANGUAGE_RESOURCES.getString( msgID );
    } catch( Throwable e ) {
        msg = "$" + msgID + "$";
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: Possibly some class which is used inside the constructor. Can you show some code (specifically Foobar:76)?

Comment: @Manish I have add code sequences

Comment: Msg is the problem. Most likely it can't find the resource bundle: LANGUAGE_RESOURCES = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "com.company.xyz.i18n.LanguageResources" );

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a library (.jar) file that is dependent on another .jar file but you do not have that dependent .jar file included in your current project. Please list full error message so we can see exact problem =D

Comment: This is the full message. Only the stacktrace is longer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is not the actual problem. There should be another exception before that.
Any access to this class will trigger NoClassDefFound but it means only that the class is not loaded. It does not tell you why. Line 76 may hold the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your code compiled against a particular version of a library, and is running against another. It's basically a linkage error.
It's not always trivial to identify the library that causes the problem, but the line number should suggest which class is being loaded at the time of the error.

*Updated*: in your posted stack trace, the error originates in the constructor (line 76) for the class com.company.xyz.FooBar, no doubt a stand-in for gov.nasa.programs.supersecret.bases.alphacentauri.

That class must have a dependency on another class that cannot be loaded at that point, most likely because it is not present in the exact version it was compiled against. Note that the actual issue could be further down the chain, so make sure to review the dependencies of that class if you rule it out.